# How to fix "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I was trying to make a command that sends random GIF in the chat, but it kept giving me errors. WHat should I do?

I am using Discord.js to code it, and the GIF is supported by Giphy API.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}gif`)) {
    fetch(
      "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=PRIVATE"
    ).then(body => {
      var body = JSON.parse(body)
      message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          color: Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777214) + 1,
          title: "**GIF Machine**",
          description: "Here's your GIF!",
          fields: [],
          timestamp: new Date(),
          image: {
            files: [body.data.image_original_url]
          },
          footer: {
            text: "Made with ❤️ created by Raymond#1725"
          }
        }
      });
    })
  }
}
```

It gives out the error:

`(node:6732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Don't try to `JSON.parse` something that isn't JSON?

Comment: Have a look at the first example in [MDN: Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: but if i remove that then `body` will not get to be defined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}gif`)) {
    fetch(
      "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=PRIVATE"
    )
    .then(res=>res.json()) // changed
    .then(body => {        // changed
      message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          color: Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777214) + 1,
          title: "**GIF Machine**",
          description: "Here's your GIF!",
          fields: [],
          timestamp: new Date(),
          image: {
            files: [body.data.image_original_url]
          },
          footer: {
            text: "Made with ❤️ created by Raymond#1725"
          }
        }
      });
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: @RaymondHsu hold on, is the request actually response JSON? or binary gif?

Comment: it responses a gif, anyways i fixed the problem